# mail() is acting weird with Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl()

Tags: php, email, yii

How does createAbsoluteUrl() act outside of controller?

I am trying send a link in email. That link is:

```
 Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('user/deactivate',  array('secret'=>$one->id,  deactivate_key'=>$one->delete_key))
```

this code works fine in a controller but not working in commands directory. That is, mail() is not sending message with createAbsoluteUrl().

How to fix this?

**Full Code:**

```
class NotifyCommand extends CConsoleCommand
{

public function run()
{

    $cr = new CDbCriteria();
    $cr->condition = "delete_key = ''";

    $model2 = User::model()->findAll($cr);

    foreach ($model2 as $one) {
        $delete_key = sha1(mt_rand(10000, 99999).time()."some string");
        $one->delete_key = $delete_key;
        $one->save(false);
    }

    $model = User::model()->findAll();

    foreach ($model as $one) {
        if($one->ban == 1){

            $last = strtotime($one->last_logon);
            $now = time();
            $difference = $now - $last;
            $month_in_seconds = 60*60*24*30;

            if($difference > $month_in_seconds){

                $message = "<p>It has been more than a month since you visited our site: Sotrudnik.uz. If you want you can delete you account by clicking the button below</p>";
                $message .= "<button><a style=\" text-decoration: none; color: black;\" href=".Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('user/deactivate',  array('secret'=>$one->id, 'deactivate_key'=>$one->delete_key)).">Deactivate Your Account</a></button>";



                $subject = "This is a subject";

                $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'From: CTI.uz' . "\r\n";

              mail($one->email,"Deactivate Your Account",$message, $headers);



            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error message if you see any? and what appears on the email on the place of this url?

Comment: cron is set up to execute the command...so I don't see any error message. No email is coming. The message basically should say: click the link below to deactivate your account.

Comment: check console log file for errors.

Comment: there is a typo in code you pasted, after `deactivate_key` you have unclosed string statement

Comment: @tinybyte, that typo is only here...my bad...in text editor it is fine

Comment: paste the full code please

Comment: I edited the question to include full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not depend on createAbsoluteUrl() in a cron.

Try this to create url

```
$link= $_SERVER['secureHostInfo'].'/user/deactivate?secret='.$one->id.'&deactivate_key='.$one->delete_key;
 $message .= CHtml::link('Click here', $link);
```

If $_SERVER['secureHostInfo'] didn't worked check your path in $_SERVER array.